# What is the easiest way to mount a network drive from an ubuntu 12.04 server?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, server

I have a pc running ubuntu 12.10.
I want to share or map storage(2TB Hard-disks)from that machine to a ubuntu server 12.04.

```
                  12.10(PC) -----------> 12.04(Server)
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You may use NFS to achieve what you need. There are some good documentation on the links below on how to make it work:

- [Setting UP NFS HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo)
- [Network File System](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html)
- [How To Set Up an NFS Mount on Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Afte some reading, I have a follow-up question: NFS vs CIFS vs Samba?

Comment: @Atrh please ask a new question (or look if there isn't one answered already).